# Multiple booting errors for 13.10

Tags: boot, 13.10

I have an Acer Aspire V5 Touch, which came with Windows 8 preinstalled. I removed it and installed Ubuntu 13.10 in its place. At first the performance was great, much better than Win8 and it booted up in under 20 seconds (HDD not SSD).

Recently however, I have been experiencing very slow boot ups and I also see the GRUB menu a lot. I'm guessing that's due to some sort of startup issue. So I ran dmesg on the terminal, which returned the following:

```
[  810.306035] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:332: I/O error writing to inode 35652078 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 858265)
[  810.306039] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[  810.306040] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[  810.306041] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
[  810.306042] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[  810.306042] Write(10): 2a 00 00 c1 52 40 00 00 08 00
[  810.306046] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:332: I/O error writing to inode 35652078 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 1583689)
[  810.306050] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[  810.306051] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[  810.306051] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
[  810.306052] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[  810.306053] Write(10): 2a 00 00 c1 6a 20 00 00 08 00
[  810.306057] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:332: I/O error writing to inode 35652078 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 1584453)
[  810.306063] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[  810.306064] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[  810.306065] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
[  810.306066] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[  810.306066] Write(10): 2a 00 39 84 4d 88 00 00 a0 00
[  810.306185] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
[  810.306943] EXT4-fs error (device sda1) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4849: Journal has aborted
[  810.307451] EXT4-fs (sda1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[  810.307454] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_journal_check_start:56: 
[  810.307456] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[  810.307458] Detected aborted journal
```

I am completely clueless as I have not messed around with any of the hardware, or opened the back of the laptop or anything like that. All I did was install Virtual box with a legitimate copy of Windows 7, if I ever need to use Windows applications without the need of Wine.

If anyone can provide any solution to this, I would be very grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: My laptop was shipped in UEFI mode so I switched to Legacy just to use Ubuntu. But I will try what you suggested and let you know. Thank you! This is a fairly new laptop, from Aug 2013.

EDIT: it has booted up but is ridiculously slow and doesn't open Firefox at all.

Edit: the file system was in read only so I ran fsck, which is fixing inodes from a corrupted orphan linked list, and deleted inodes which have zero dtime. There are a lot more things which were fixed. But luckily I have all of the data on the laptop backed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen these symptoms before, and typically it indicates that the controller is having trouble writing to the disk, most likely because that disk is bad.  Sometimes it is due to a fall, other times, just a bad batch of disks. Also please let us know if you have recently tweaked a BIOS setting related to disks, like AHCI/Legacy mode or similar. I recommend using an external tool to diagnose your disk issue.

1) Back up everything important off that disk.  Do **not** wait.

2) Get Parted Magic - the last 'free' version is 8/2013.  I've seen it on Major Geeks, or you can contribute to Patrick and get the latest version at partedmagic.com.

3) Burn it to a CD or use UNetBootIn (on Linux/Windows) or Rufus (Windows Only) to write it to USB.  I recommend USB. But please don't use the one you backed your stuff up on from step one, because this requires a USB format.

4) In Parted Magic, use the GSmartTool to identify if your disk is dying.  If any attributes are pink, it is probably time to replace the disk.  Especially reallocated sectors or Read/Write failure.  Don't wait for a SMART error from the BIOS.  I've only seen one in 20 years of working on computers.

Good luck!

Comment: Had to get the HDD replaced, thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry you lost your HDD, hopefully you didn't lose too much data.  Good luck with Ubuntu.